# Python - Processing Unicode (Russian) Txt file

Tags: python, cyrillic

I have been puzzling for the last few hours in a Russian tab delimited txt file. Here is how it looks like:

```
CODE    AD_GROUP    KEYWORD MATCH_TYPE

009966  Автостраховка   автостраховка   Broad
009965  Автостраховка   страховкаавто   Broad
009964  Автостраховка   страховка автомобиля    Broad
```

The goal is to parse the txt file and for now print each keyword separately.

So far I have:

```
f = open("struct.txt",encoding="UTF-8",errors='strict')

for line in f:
    vals = line.split("\t")
    print(vals[2])

f.close()
```

But I keep getting the following errors:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Also, if I do a len(vals) to see the length of each list I get the following: 4 1 4 1 which probably means the split("\") is not working?

I am using Python3.3 and a mac.

Lastly, I don't think it is a problem with the command line on the mac not displaying Cyrillic characters - it has done it before without problems (western Windows versions seems to fail at that).

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: The Unicode error is only about the print in the command line. You can execute your script in IDLE and it should work. Then you can get a proper output and debug while the lengths are not working as expected.

Comment: You are experiencing a print failure. You need to fix your terminal setup. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but that doesn't seem to be the problem (as mentioned in my description). I just ran it in IDLE on mac and got: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: How do you see that file with the characters? What program are you using? perhaps the file is UTF-16

Comment: Hi Mark, please see my comment below to sberry. Got it working partially!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this code (Python2.7)

```
f = open("struct.txt")

for line in f:
    vals = [item for item in line.strip().split("\t") if item != '']
    if len(vals):
        print(vals[2])

f.close()
```

And your source (which I edited to make sure it had tabs) I get the following output:

```
> python so_16703270.py
KEYWORD
автостраховка
страховкаавто
страховка автомобиля
```

Are you sure you have tabs throughout in the file and not spaces in some places?

Comment: Hi sberry, I did some further digging and found out when it "does" and "does not" work. If I take the data from an excel file and paste it into notepad and save as struct.txt (UTF-8 encoding) then it does work. However, if I save the excel file as Unicode txt it stops working and the file size is also bigger. Why do you think that is? Also, what would be the recommendation to save the file as if I am using excel to build the columns in the first place? If I try .csv then the Cyrillic characters break :-( Thank you and looking forward to the advice!